# at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)

Tags: android, string, web-services, nullpointerexception, init

I am creating an android app in which i am sending data to the web service but i am getting this error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228
```

here is my code

```
for(int li=0;li<timerlist.size();li++)
            {
                String finish_pos=String.valueOf(li+1);
                int event_id=Integer.parseInt(series_event_raceid);
                 jObjectType.put("FinishPosition", finish_pos); 
                jObjectType.put("RaceTime", convertedtime.get(li));
                  jObjectType.put("SeriesEventRaceID", event_id);
                 jsonarraylist.add(jObjectType.toString());
                 }
```

Stack trace:

```
08-11 12:24:29.951: W/System.err(5262): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 12:24:29.951: W/System.err(5262):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)
08-11 12:24:29.951: W/System.err(5262):     at com.example1.racerunner.Timenewrace$5.onFailure(Timenewrace.java:394)
08-11 12:24:29.955: W/System.err(5262):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:284)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:134)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 12:24:29.959: W/System.err(5262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 12:24:29.963: W/System.err(5262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think this series_event_raceid contain null value please debug it.

Comment: i checked it contains value

Comment: @user3614978 Can you post the whole stack trace? I want to see which line throws the error. Or try to execute it line by line by putting breakpoints on each line and see what is the last line that gets executed.

Comment: i posted logcat please check my edited question

Comment: @Haresh line 228 is in the implementation of `String` class. Nothing to do with this.

Comment: elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; this is line 228

Comment: What is line 394 in `Timenewrace.java`?

Comment: String val = null;
     try {
      val = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
      Log.i("Fail", val);
     } 
these line are 393 to 397

Comment: actual 394 line is try {

Comment: what is `arg2`? It might be `null`.

Comment: Are you sure it is not null?